# Confusion with JavaScript increment (++)

Tags: javascript

I'm learning JavaScript and just came across something I'm not understanding.

```js
let x = 3;
const y = x++;

console.log(x);
```

The console logs 4. Why is x logged as 4, when y is a separate variable and seemingly not affecting x? Is x++ not simply being assigned to y? And in that case, why would the value of x be changed?

Comment: `++` always increments the variable it operates on.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Increment. "The increment operator (++) increments (adds one to) its operand and returns a value.

"

Comment: Related question, what do you think logging `y` will return?

Comment: I see that it logs 3 - which I don't understand either.

Comment: Read the link I posted and it should make sense